# Compare a date with specific date format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have column of type varchar in a table and have different type of date format in it. I want to compare it with specific format of date. If it is true then those rows should be returned only. Format of the date is 'yyyymmdd'

e.g., `20200831 = 'yyyymmdd'`

dates are in below format

```
20200831
31/Aug/2020
08-31-2020
2020-08-31
```

These are few date format which are present in the table.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, a possible solution is the following statement:

```
SELECT DateText
FROM (VALUES
   ('20200831'),
   ('31/Aug/2020'),
   ('08-31-2020'),
   ('2020-08-31')
) v (DateText)
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(8), TRY_CONVERT(date, DateText), 112) = DateText
```

Result:

```
DateText
20200831
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution has really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE ISDATE(dateCol) = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(dateCol) = 1;
```

[ISDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function returns 1 if column value is valid SQL Server date
and [ISNUMERIC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns 1 if column value is valid number, so 20200831 satisfies both conditiion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, then the `TRY_CONVERT` function is one option here:

```
SELECT
    dt,
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, dt) AS dt_out
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, dt) = '2020-08-31';
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

**Data:**

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '20200831' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '31/Aug/2020' UNION ALL
    SELECT '08-31-2020'  UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020-08-31'
)
```